# pymsql (1054, "Unknown column 'None' in 'call statement'")

Tags: python, sql, pymysql

I am trying to call stored procedure with pymsql but it looks like I am getting an error when one of the param is passed in as None. My stored proc is able to handle cases of Null but ofcourse not None. I was under the impression that pymysql automatically converts None to Null. Below is the code I am using.

```
_exec_statement = 'call kp_get_purchase_order(None,10,0)'
self.cursor.execute(_exec_statement)
return self.cursor.fetchall()
```

> Error: pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'None' in
> 'call statement'")

Is there a way to convert None to Null to pass into the cursor?

Comment: use null instead of None, except the SQL script expects \`None\` as varchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead.

```
_exec_statement = 'call kp_get_purchase_order(None,10,0)'.replace('None', 'null')
self.cursor.execute(_exec_statement)
```

> was under the impression that pymysql automatically converts None to Null.

Yes. But only in a context where the `None` is visible, such as this:

```
_exec_statement = 'call kp_get_purchase_order(%s)'
args = (None, 10, 0)
self.cursor.execute(_exec_statement, *args)
```